# DAX - Rankx by multiple Categories Issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have 4 Categories (GP, ID, Age, Date). I would would like to create calculated column and group by GP, ID, and Age and Rank/ count by Date to see how many months each member has in past 24 month.

My Code works until I have members who cancelled their membership for a few months and then resumed after.  I need to restart from the first month after skip. for example :

```
GP  ID  AGE     DATE    RKING Desired RANK
1   220 35-44   202206  12     6
1   220 35-44   202205  12     5
1   220 35-44   202204  12     4
1   220 35-44   202203  12     3
1   220 35-44   202202  12     2
1   220 35-44   202201  12     1
1   220 35-44   202012  24     24
1   220 35-44   202011  23     23
1   220 35-44   202010  22     22
1   220 35-44   202009  21     21
1   220 35-44   202008  20     20
1   220 35-44   202007  19     19
1   220 35-44   202006  18     18
1   220 35-44   202005  17     17
1   220 35-44   202004  16     16
…    …   …       …      …      …
1   220 35-44   201901  1      1
```

This is what I have tried but doesn't work for dates skipping.

```
RKING Column= 
RANKX (
CALCULATETABLE (
               VALUES ('tbl'[Date] ),
               ALLEXCEPT ( 'tblW', 'tbl'[GP], 'tbl'[ID] ),
                         'tbl'[AGE] = 'tbl'[AGE],
                         'tbl'[date] >= start_date && 'tbl'[date] <= end_date // date slicer
                ),
[Date] ,
,ASC
)
```

Comment: Hello,  I think 2nd argument of RANKX should be an expression to be evaluated in the row context of calculate table. [Date] should not be there. It must be like 'CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(VALUES([Date])))'. Also What is the purpose of this filter 'tbl'[AGE] = 'tbl'[AGE] ?

Comment: Thanks @OzanSen !!  the age range to keep track of member age because of some business roles. 
Also, CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(VALUES([Date]))), produces result in a clac column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking through the code you were trying to make a measure for a visual (For a calcCol the measure is added as well). And as I got a point, you want to show a sum of consequtive months in a matrix for each date in accordance to ID/GP/AGE/DATE I see a following way.
As you know, calculations performs for each row in a matrix and filter the data model according to data presented in matrix rows and columns (slicers as well). So, my idea is -

1. Get date from matrixRow and use it as max date for the table.
2. Then use a FILTER(). FILTER() is an iterative function, so it goes throw each row and checks filtering condition - if true row remains if false - not.

I use following filtring conditions:

Get dateInMatrix-dateInACurrentTableRow (for example: `202203-202201= 2 months`)
Then check how many rows in the table with `min=202201` and `max<202203`
if there are less rows then date difference then it FALSE() and the row is out of table.
3) The last step is counting of rows it a filtered table.

A measure for matrix:

```
Ranking = 
VAR matrixDate=MAX('table'[DATE])
VAR filteredTable = 
         FILTER(
            ALL('table')
            ,DATEDIFF(
                DATE(LEFT([DATE],4),RIGHT([DATE],2),1)
                ,DATE(LEFT(matrixDate,4),RIGHT(matrixDate,2),1)
                ,MONTH
            )
            =
                VAR dateInRow=[DATE]
                RETURN
                    CALCULATE(
                        COUNTROWS('table')
                        ,'table'[DATE]>=dateInRow
                        ,'table'[DATE]<matrixDate
                    )
        )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(filteredTable)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

A measure for calcColl:

```
RankColl = 
VAR currentDate=[Start_Date]
Var MyFilt={('Table'[AGE],'Table'[ID],'Table'[GROUP])}
VAR withColl = 
         ADDCOLUMNS(
            CALCULATETABLE(
                'table'
                ,ALL('Table')
                ,TREATAS(MyFilt,'Table'[AGE],'Table'[ID],'Table'[GROUP])
            )
            ,"dateDiff",
                        DATEDIFF(
                            [Start_Date]
                            ,currentDate
                            ,MONTH
                        )
            ,"RowsInTable",
                VAR dateInRow=[Start_Date]
                Var startDate=IF(dateInRow<currentDate,dateInRow,currentDate)
                VAR endDay =IF(dateInRow>currentDate,dateInRow,currentDate)
                VAR myDates = GENERATESERIES(startDate,endDay,1)
                RETURN
                    COUNTROWS(
                        CALCULATETABLE(
                            'Table'
                            ,ALL('Table')
                            ,TREATAS(MyFilt,'Table'[AGE],'Table'[ID],'Table'[GROUP])
                            ,TREATAS(myDates,'Table'[Start_Date])
                        )
                    )
        )
VAR filtered =
        FILTER(
            withColl
            ,[dateDiff]=[RowsInTable]-1  -- for ex.:
                                         -- dateDiff=01/01/2022-01/01/2022=0, 
                                         -- but it will be 1 row in the table for 01/01/2022
        )
RETURN
    CountRows( filtered)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mik! That was genius :) I will try it and let you know.

Comment: There are 2 codes, one for measure, the second for column.

Comment: Please, let me know if it,ok.

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach your file? not sure why mine it's not working. thank you!!

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GbKqfn4TorU3H2ht-RccljF6p0vk1HsD/view?usp=sharing I was doing that )

Comment: You can attach yours, so I can check it tomorrow.

Comment: i have more columns in my actual table, could it be because of them? https://drive.google.com/file/d/12_p8enlom4XXq3ha4PLzvtsfHCQcWK5V/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SamR, I changed the measure. Please check. New columns didn't affect the measure. The problem was in the measue and new values showed that.  I used a `[Start Date]` for calculations. It's possible to use `[DATE]` cloumn, but there were incorrect values for ex. `202171`. So, if you dont want t use [Start Date], please, correct the field values and let me know if you want to use [DATE]. And, please, confirm that the measure is correct. I changed the code in the answer.